# Line Plot based on a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to learn how to analyze data in python, so I'm using a database that I've already did some work on it with PowerBI, but now I'm trying to do the same plots with python.
[The Pandas dataframe is this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duntu.png)

[And I'm trying to build a line plot like this one...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msirN.png)

This line represents the amount of 'Água e sabonete' and 'Fricção com álcool' in the column Ação divided by the the totals of Ação.
This was how managed to do it on PowerBI using Dax:

```
Adesão = VAR nReal = (COUNTROWS(FILTER(Tabela1,Tabela1[Ação]="Água e sabonete")) + COUNTROWS(FILTER(Tabela1,Tabela1[Ação]="Fricção com álcool")))
       //VAR acao = COUNTA(Tabela1[Ação]
RETURN
    DIVIDE(nReal,COUNTA(Tabela1[Ação]))
```

I want to know if it is possible to do something similar to build the plot or if there is other way to build it in python.

I didn't try anything especifically, but I think that should be possible to build it with a function, but it is too difficult to me right now to create one since I'm a beginner.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to get access to each month and count every time Água e sabonete and Fricção com álcool appear.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def dateprod(year): #could change this with an array of each month instead 
  year = str(year) + "-"
  dates = []
  for i in range(1,13):
    if i >= 10:
      date = year + str(i)
    else:
      date = year + "0" + str(i)
    dates.append(date)
  return dates

def y_construct(year,search_1,search_2):
  y_vals = np.zeros(0)
  for j in dateprod(2001): 
    score = 0
    temp_list = df.loc[str(j)]["aloc"].values #Gets all values of each month
    for k in temp_list:
      if k == str(search_1) or str(search_2): #Cheak if the words in the arrays are time Água e sabonete and Fricção com álcool
        score += 1
    y_vals = np.append(y_vals,score) 
  return y_vals/df.size # divid by total. Assuming that the amount of Ação is the same as df.size

# this does the plotting
y_vals = y_construct(2022,"Água e sabonete","Fricção com álcool")
x_label = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jul","juli","aug","sep","otc","nov","dec"]
plt.ylabel("%")
plt.plot(x_label,y_vals)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I'm getting an error on this line: temp_list = df.loc[str(j)]["aloc"].values
KeyError: '2001-01'